# Prove that the initial value problem: $yy'=x$, $y(0)=0$ has more than one solution

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

$yy'=x \implies y\frac{dy}{dx}=x \implies ydy=xdx\implies \int y\ dy= \int x\ dx \implies \frac{y^2}{2}=\frac{x^2}{2} + C_1 \implies y^2=x^2+C \implies y=\pm \sqrt{x^2+C}$

$y(0)=0 \implies \pm \sqrt{0^2+C}=0 \implies \pm \sqrt{C}=0 \implies C=0$

I don't see how to it has more than one solution. What am I missing?

Comment: Both $y=x$ and $y = -x$ are solutions.

Comment: $C=0$ is right... the $\pm$ is where the second solution comes from.  The solutions would seem to be $y=x$ and $y=-x$.